# How to know the amount of heap used by an ElasticSearch shard?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster where several indices in the warm nodes don't contain any documents. As they are read-only, they can't get any more documents, so I want to know if removing them will do any good to the heap usage of my ElasticSearch nodes.

I tried using the `/_cat/shards` to get some heap information per shard of said indices, but I couldn't find it, I tried looking at the values of the following metrics, but even for 20GiB shards the values are so small I think I'm looking at the wrong metrics (in parentheses the sample value for a 33GiB shard):

- `fm: fielddata.memory_size (0b)`
- `qcm: query_cache.memory_size (0b)`
- `sm: segments.memory (44.6mb)`
- `siwm: segments.index_writer_memory (0b)`
- `svmm: segments.version_map_memory (0b)`
- `sfbm: segments.fixed_bitset_memory (0b)`

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to know how much host memory is being by each shard?
- Does an empty shard consume any heap?

(The bottom line is my warm nodes is having high heap, so I'm considering removing all the shards of these empty indices, but only if it would have any benefit at all.)

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want: there is a variable called: `ES_HEAP_SIZE` in this file: `/etc/default/elasticsearch`... also [this thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-check-es-heap-size/36613/6) might help...

Comment: Thanks. Though that variable (and the link) are for finding the total heap used by ES. What I would like to know is how much each individual shard contributes to that heap usage.

Comment: *I have a cluster where several shards in the warm nodes don't contain any documents.* Just to be clear: Does your entire index don't contain any documents or only particular shards? For example: your index is made up of say 5 shards and  only 2 of them don't contain data but the other three do. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill None of the shards of this index contain any documents. So I actually want to delete the whole index.

Comment: So why are you hesitant to do it?

Comment: To do it, I need to modify my maintenance application's code (it won't be one time cleanup, it's an ongoing automatic cleanup). So, before writing the software to do the cleaning of the 700 indices that are empty, I want to know if there would be any gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after gathering some information through the comment section here are my two cents:

First of all, I am not aware of an API that lets you inspect the heap memory per shard. *Maybe* xpack monitoring and/or the elasticsearch metricbeat module can do that for you.

However since you asked:

> ... As they are read-only, they can't get any more documents, **so I want to know if removing them will do any good to the heap usage of my ElasticSearch nodes.**

Elasticsearch is built on top of Lucene. A Lucene index is made up of one or more immutable index segments, which essentially is a "mini-index". Elasticsearch tries to keep frequently requested segments (indexing- and search-requests) in the heap memory in order to serve these requests in a fast manner. If no more segments can be loaded into the heap (because the heap size has reached its limit), segments get flushed to disk and other segments get loaded from disk into the heap. This is a constant process (take a look at this [blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up#index-segments) for reference).

As you have stated the indices that you consider "problematic" are read-only (meaning no indexing-requests can be performed) and also contain no documents (meaning no search-requests will be executed against the particular segments).

**To sum it up: The "problematic" indices will most likely not be in the *heap* anyways.**

Yet, these indices however still claim some disk space because of the fact that they "exist". Furthermore elasticsearch must manage their shards and has to (re-)allocate them to nodes, e.g. in case of an shard recovery.

> Q: So why are you hesitant to do *(deleting the empty indices)* it?
>
> A: ... I need to modify my maintenance application's code...

With Elasticsearch version 6.6 came [index lifecycle management (ilm)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html). It's aim is to automate the management/maintenance of indices by defining policies. These policies contain so called phases (hot, warm, cold, delete) and corresponding actions (rollover, read-only, freeze, shrink, delete, ...). They can also be setup and modified through Kibana.

You *may* want to take a look at ilm and replace your application with it (no offense, just a hint).

I hope I could help you!

Comment: Thanks, we're planning to start using ILM some day, just that it came after we had already been using our own ILM for some years, so migrating will take time.